# Как грузить только нужный размер?

Tags: html, css, веб-дизайн

Привет, есть такая задача. Есть иконки в формате pixel art. Дизайнер нарисовал их 3900 на 3000. В проекте их размер варьируется в зависимости от размера экрана. Но если брать к примеру самый большой размер 2560(34") то их размер составляет 377px. Т.е он грузит изображение в 10-15 раз больше. Посоветуйте пожалуйста что делать в данной ситуации

Comment: Тут ясно и понятно написано, думаю разберешься
https://webref.ru/layout/html5-css3/img/scale

Comment: дак и уменьшите его до размера в 377px, если больше вам все равно не надо

Answer (score 0):

1) Уменьшить изображения через графический редактор

2) использовать тэг [`<picture>`](https://htmlhook.ru/html5-picture-dlya-izobrazhenij.html)

Comment: Ссылка на тэг битая, вот актуальная: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture